# nth-child issue with jquery accordion with odd/ even rows

Tags: jquery, css, accordion, css-selectors

I have a jquery accordion that I want to use nth-child to assign odd / even backgrounds to.

The structure is like this :

```
<div class="jobmenu accordion">
    <a>
        <section>
            <article><img.....></article>
            <article>Item 1 name</article>
            <article>123</article>
        </section>
    </a> 
    <div>
        <table class="itemTable">
            <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody>...</tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
    <a>
        <section>
            <article><img.....></article>
            <article>Item 2 name</article>
            <article>432</article>
        </section>
    </a> 
    <div>
        <table class="itemTable">
            <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody>...</tbody>
        </table>
    </div>     
</div>
```

nth-child works perfectly on the tables assigning odd and even values to the trs in tbody, but I want to do the same with the accordion.  the articles are all working correctly with set widths for the nth-child to have a uniform look to the collapsable list but every "a" is assigned to the odd style. unless I physically add a class to it in the php, but that defeats the point of clean css design.

css is :

```
.jobmenu a {
    height:40px;
}

.jobmenu a:nth-child(even){
    background: #CCC;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position: relative; /*To help in the anchoring of the ".statusicon" icon imageglossyback.gif*/
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.jobmenu a:nth-child(odd){
    background: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position: relative; /*To help in the anchoring of the ".statusicon" icon imageglossyback.gif*/
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.jobmenu article:nth-child(1)
{
    width:350px; margin-left:15px; text-wrap:normal; float:left;
}

.jobmenu article:nth-child(2)
{
    width:100px; float:left;
}

.jobmenu article:nth-child(3)
{
    width:200px; float:left;
}
```

I'm assuming it's because the a's are in the odd position and the divs are in the even.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.jobmenu a:nth-child(4n+1){
    /*style*/
}
```

I tried and it works.